# 'no listener' error on Jasper Report Printing

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports, oracle-apex

I am using `Oracle Apex 5.0.3` running on `Oracle 11.0.2 SE 1`, Apex is configured using `ORDS 3.0.6`. I have configured `Jasper Report` in `Apache Tomcat 7.0.75`.

In my Oracle Apex Application, when I click on the `Print` button, I am getting this error.

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP",
line 1130 ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

Below is my code, which is invoking which button click.

```
BEGIN
         -- call the report and pass parameters
        xlib_jasperreports.set_report_url('http://127.0.0.1:8080/JasperReportsIntegration/report');
        xlib_jasperreports.show_report (p_rep_name          => 'PATH/TO/REPORT_NAME',
                                        p_rep_format        => 'pdf',
                                        p_data_source       => 'default',
                                        p_out_filename      => 'Users_info.pdf',
                                        p_rep_locale        => 'en_US'
                                       );

        -- stop rendering of the current APEX page
        apex_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
END;
```

I have properly granted ACL rights to my schema.
Please suggest any fix for this issue, if anyone has ran through.

Comment: This could have a couple of causes, especially the listner of the client not started.

Comment: @J.Chomel My Listener is running absolutely find, I also reloaded the Listener, but getting same error.

Comment: Does your client call *this very* listener? Or does it try to use another one?

Comment: My client is using same Listener only. The whole configuration is on the same single server.

Comment: @J.Chomel, Issue is resolved, I have put in the answer. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, Actually port 8080 was opened in `iptable` but `server.xml` in `Apache Tomcat` was not configured to listen port 8080.

Once I configured port 8080 in server.xml, I was able to get response without any error.